# SSL error when attempting to install custom kernel module

Tags: drivers, kernel, keyboard-backlight

I recently purchased a Clevo P950HR on which I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have managed to get most things running on it, except for the keyboard backlight, which annoyingly I cannot turn off. Luckily, there is an opensource project which provides a driver for this model (https://bitbucket.org/tuxedocomputers/clevo-xsm-wmi). I cloned the repository and built the driver, but invoking `make && make install` gives me this error:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.10.0-37-generic/build M=/home/timo/clevo-xsm-wmi/module modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-37-generic'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-37-generic'
make -C /lib/modules/4.10.0-37-generic/build M=/home/timo/clevo-xsm-wmi/module modules_install
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-37-generic'
  INSTALL /home/timo/clevo-xsm-wmi/module/clevo-xsm-wmi.ko
cp: cannot create regular file '/lib/modules/4.10.0-37-generic/extra/clevo-xsm-wmi.ko': Permission denied
At main.c:158:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  DEPMOD  4.10.0-37-generic
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-37-generic
```

So I had a bit of a google around and apparently this has to do with the fact that kernel modules need to be cryptographically signed by the people at canonical in Ubuntu 16.04. So I also read that I should be able to install this using dkms, I tried that but to no avail...I was wondering if someone might be able to help me out, if you can please make the instructions nice and clear as I am not a super-experienced linux user.

This is the exact version of Ubuntu I am using:

```
4.10.0-37-generic #41~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 6 22:42:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Many thanks!